# How to get the kernel version of the next boot from a script

Tags: kernel, boot

I need to find out which kernel will be used for the next boot, regardless of current running kernel, and this is done in a shell script.

There could be multiple kernels installed, GRUB is configured to boot one, and this could change by kernel upgrade/downgrades. So the script needs to  find out what will be the kernel for the next boot.

One approach is to parse the default kernel from GRUB configurations. The default GRUB menu entry can be detected, for example:

```bsh
grep GRUB_DEFAULT /etc/default/grub | cut -d '=' -f 2
```

Then get the menu entries from GRUB config, like:

```bsh
grep -A 15 '^menuentry' /boot/grub/grub.cfg  | grep -o -P 'vmlinuz-\S+'
```

and find the right menu entry by matching the index with the configured default one.

For my specific case there is no need to cover for GRUB `saved` entries, but would be nice if that was also covered.

Is there any better/cleaner way to get this information?

Comment: Presumably the guarantee lasts only until the script finishes, as grub could be updated any time?

Comment: Yes of course. It needs to detect the kernel version to be booted, at the time the script started running. The next run may have a different output (if GRUB config was updated while the script ran).

Comment: Note that just parsing the config file might fail if grub was set up to boot the last kernel (`GRUB_SAVE_DEFAULT=0`,  `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved`)

Comment: Thanks for the note @EduardoTrápani , as mentioned in the question covering `saved` defaults is not intended in my own case, but if a solution covers that as well, it could be helpful for someone else reading this question later, if any. :)